# How to get the glow color of a text in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have some textfields with glow added thru AS3 like the code bellow.

```
    var glow:GlowFilter = new GlowFilter();
    glow.color = 0x00FFFF;
    glow.alpha = 1;
    glow.blurX = 5;
    glow.blurY = 5;
    glow.quality = BitmapFilterQuality.HIGH;

    textfield1.filters = [glow];
```

I'd like to know if is there a function to retrieve the glow color!

Something like this:

```
textfield2.getGlowFilter.color;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no function for that. But you could loop through the filters array, look for the filter and get its color once you find it.

Something like this (untested):

```
for(var i:int = 0; i < textfield1.filters.length;i++) {
    if(textfield1.filters[i] is GlowFilter) {
        textfield1.filters[i].color;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer has already been accepted for this question but before it was, I was working on a class that would make getting a specific `BitmapFilter` easier, oh well, I'll post my answer anyway.

Filters.as:

```
package filters 
{
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;
    import flash.filters.BevelFilter
    import flash.filters.BitmapFilter;
    import flash.filters.BlurFilter
    import flash.filters.ColorMatrixFilter
    import flash.filters.ConvolutionFilter
    import flash.filters.DisplacementMapFilter
    import flash.filters.DropShadowFilter
    import flash.filters.GlowFilter
    import flash.filters.GradientBevelFilter
    import flash.filters.GradientGlowFilter

    public class Filters 
    {
        public static var throwsError:Boolean;

        public static function getBevelFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):BevelFilter
        {
            return BevelFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, BevelFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function getBlurFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):BlurFilter
        {
            return BlurFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, BlurFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function getColorMatrixFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):ColorMatrixFilter
        {
            return ColorMatrixFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, ColorMatrixFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function getConvolutionFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):ConvolutionFilter
        {
            return ConvolutionFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, ConvolutionFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function getDisplacementMapFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):DisplacementMapFilter
        {
            return DisplacementMapFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, DisplacementMapFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function getDropShadowFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):DropShadowFilter
        {
            return DropShadowFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, DropShadowFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function getGlowFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):GlowFilter
        {
            return GlowFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, GlowFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function getGradientBevelFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):GradientBevelFilter
        {
            return GradientBevelFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, GradientBevelFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function getGradientGlowFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject):GradientGlowFilter
        {
            return GradientGlowFilter(getBitmapFilter(displayObject, GradientGlowFilter));

        }// end function

        public static function updateFilters(displayObject:DisplayObject, ...bitmapFilters:Array):void
        {
            for (var i:uint = 0; i < bitmapFilters.length; i++)
            {
                if (!(bitmapFilters[i] is BitmapFilter))
                {
                    throw new ArgumentError("bitmapFilters argument must be of type BitmapFilter");

                }// end if

            }// end for             
            var filterArray:Array = new Array();

            for each(var bitmapFilter:BitmapFilter in displayObject.filters)
            {
                filterArray.push(bitmapFilter);

            }// end for             

            for (var j:uint = 0; j < filterArray.length; j++)
            {
                for (var k:uint = 0; k < bitmapFilters.length; k++)
                {
                    if (filterArray[j] is Class(Object(bitmapFilters[k]).constructor))
                    {
                        filterArray[j] = bitmapFilters[k];

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (throwsError) throw new Error("One or more bitmapFilters arguments did not exist in the display object's filters array");

                    }// end else

                }// end for

            }// end for

            displayObject.filters = filterArray;


        private static function getBitmapFilter(displayObject:DisplayObject, BitmapFilterClass:Class):BitmapFilter
        {
            var bitmapFilter:BitmapFilter;

            for each(var bf:BitmapFilter in displayObject.filters)
            {
                if (bf is BitmapFilterClass)
                {
                    bitmapFilter = bf;
                    break;

                }// end if

            }// end for

            if (!bitmapFilter && throwsError)
            throw new Error("Could not find BitmapFilter");

            return bitmapFilter;

        }// end function

    }// end class

}// end package
```

Main.as:

```
package 
{
    import filters.Filters;
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.filters.GlowFilter;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

        }// end function

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);

            var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
            sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
            sprite.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 100);
            sprite.graphics.endFill();
            sprite.filters = [new GlowFilter()];
            sprite.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
            sprite.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
            addChild(sprite);

            var spriteGlowFilter:GlowFilter = Filters.getGlowFilter(sprite);
            spriteGlowFilter.blurX = 10;
            spriteGlowFilter.blurY = 10;

            sprite.filters = [spriteGlowFilter];

        }// end function


    }// end class

}//end package
```

**[UPDATE]**

This update is in response to Juan Pablo Califano's first comment. The problem with  "Changing the last line to `return new BitmapFilterClass();`" is that it would return a new instance of `BitmapFilter`, when what we want is to return the reference of the `BitmapFilter` instance thats already in the display object's `filters` property's array.

For example we create a `Sprite` object and add a new instance of `GlowFilter` to its `filters` property, setting the color argument to `0xFFFF00`(yellow):

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
sprite.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 100);
sprite.graphics.endFill();
sprite.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xFFFF00)];
sprite.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
sprite.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
addChild(sprite);
```

Now when we trace the `color` property of the returned `GlowFilter` object using the public static `getGlowFilter` method we get the following:

```
trace(Filters.getGlowFilter(sprite).color); // output: 16776960(0xFFFF00, yellow);
```

However if we altered the code like suggested we would get the following:

```
trace(Filters.getGlowFilter(sprite).color); // output: 16711680(0xFF0000, red);
```

Now a simpler way to avoid getting an error from accessing a null value is to use a contional statement:

```
if (Filters.getGlowFilter(sprite) != null)
{
    var spriteGlowFilter:GlowFilter = Filters.getGlowFilter(sprite);
    spriteGlowFilter.blurX = 10;
    spriteGlowFilter.blurY = 10;
    sprite.filters = [spriteGlowFilter];

}// end if
```

**[UPDATE 2]**

I've updated the `Filters` class to incorparate a simple error handling feature that throws an error if a `BitmapFilter` can't be found when using a public static method like `getBevelFilter()`. This feature can be toggled on and off by setting a respective true or false boolean value to the public static property `throwsError`.

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
sprite.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 100);
sprite.graphics.endFill();
sprite.filters = [new GlowFilter(0xFFFF00)];
sprite.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
sprite.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
addChild(sprite);

Filters.throwsError = true;
Filters.getDropShadowFilter(sprite); // error: Could not find BitmapFilter
```

**[UPDATE 3]**

In response to Juan Pablo Califano's second comment, I've added the public static method `updateFilters()` which is pretty self explanatory so I'll simple show an example of its use:

```
var sprite:Sprite = new Sprite();
sprite.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
sprite.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 100);
sprite.graphics.endFill();
sprite.filters = [new GlowFilter()];
sprite.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;
sprite.y = stage.stageHeight / 2;
addChild(sprite);

Filters.throwsError = true;

var glowFilter:GlowFilter = Filters.getGlowFilter(sprite);
glowFilter.blurX = glowFilter.blurY += 10;

Filters.updateFilters(sprite, glowFilter);
```

Comment: @Taurayi. Perhaps you could return a new instance of the requested filter in your `getBitmapFilter` if none was found. Changing the last line to `return new BitmapFilterClass();` should do it. That way, you wouldn't need to check whether the return value of `Filters.getGlowFilter(sprite)` is `null` (in which case you'd get an `Error`).

Comment: @Taurayi. Also, a very useful enhancement to your class, I think, would a `addToFiltersArray(filter)` method (or something alonge these lines). The idea is that you could have more than one filter applied to your objetc. If you just do `sprite.filters = [theFilter];` you're nuking other filters. The proper way is merging the filter into a new array and assigning it, which is a lot of boilerplate. So, this method could do this for you and return an array that you can assign to the filters property safely..

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano thanks for the comments, although I agree with your second comment, I have to disagree with your first. I've explained why I disagreed with your first comment in my answer's update. As for your second comment, I know that `sprite.filters = [spriteGlowFilter];` sets the `filters` property to a new array thus effectively replacing the previous array and all its `BitmapFilter` elements, but because it was one `BitmapFilter` element in an array, it didn't seem like a big deal to replace it the lazy way. However, nothing about programming should be lazy, so I'll update the...

Comment: ...`Filters` class and add a public static method that updates a `BitmapFilter` element in the `filters` property's array rather than just replacing the entire array.

Comment: @Taurayi. Regarding my first comment, I thought your code returned the filter immediately after finding it, but you actually have a break after setting the `bitmapFilter` variable (my bad, that's how I usually write this kind of stuff -early returns- and I didn't take a closer look). At any rate, what I meant is return the filter, if found, or return a new instance otherwise. That way, the "client" code could be terser and you could avoid the null check altoghether (at least in this use-case, returning a new instance if none is found makes sense to me).

Comment: @Juan Pablo Califano I agree the client code can do without the imposing null check but I still disagree about returning a new instance of `BitmapFilter`. Imagine you want to increment the values of the `blurX` and `blurY` properties of a `GlowFilter` object thats been assigned to a dislay object's `filters` property. Now to do this, you would get the `blurX` and `blurY` values and use a `+=` compound assignment operator to add a new value to the previous one. Can you see the problem with using a new instance now?...

Comment: ...However the null check is just as bad, so I updated the code(update 2) to meet you in the middle. Now in regards to your second comment, I updated the code yet again(update 3). Its funny how much work I'm putting into an answer that will never be accepted or voted up since it will never see the light of day. However I'm glad you helped me to improve it just in case it can be useful to someone.

Comment: @Taurayi. Maybe we disagree or maybe I didn't state clearly my idea. Which is this: if you find a GlowFilter, return it (that is, don't create a new instance). If you don't find one, return a new one instead (in code: `if(bf is BitmapFilterClass){return bf;}`). The idea is that if your display object doesn't have such a filter already , you create a -let's call it- default one. You'll find arguments in favor of that, but someone could reasonably argue against it too, so ultimately it's a design decision. It's your code after all, so that's up to you.

Comment: By the way, my comments were intended to suggest (and discuss) a few ideas about how one could possibly improve it (which is the idea of this site, I think); that doesn't necessarily mean actually writting an implementation. However, I appreciate all the work you've put into your answer, and I'm sure other will do too.